# What's the meaning of "gimme shame"

Tags: meaning, green-day

I am trying to translate a *Green Day* song called "Holy Toledo!".But I don't know what is the meaning of "gimme shame".

Lyrics :

> I wanna go where the trouble begins
> And the morning after smells just like a dirty ashtray
> Oh, **gimme shame**, lock me in the shower

Let's say I'm the guy of the music.

- Am I ashamed (disappointed) because of the situation.
- Is it like: I want you to pity me or I want you to feel sorry for me.
- The situation itself makes me feel sad.
- ???

I would appreciate it if you have another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lyrics of this song are ironic. The concept is that the singer/narrator wants or craves a lot of clearly negative things and emotions. "Shame" is one of those things.

> I wanna go where the trouble begins

Who would want to look for trouble?

> And the morning after smells just like a dirty ashtray

The "morning after" is when you wake up after a one-night-stand (casual, one-time sexual experience). In this case, he WANTS it to smell like a dirty ashtray, reflecting his desire for a degrading, unpleasant experience.

> Oh, give me shame,

He wants to feel ashamed

> lock me in the shower

This is an unpleasant prank that might be played on someone in an institution --as the next line suggests, either prison or school.

And so forth...